# Register an event at the start of event queue in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

As we all know, events are attached & executed in a way they are registered i.e. FIFO.

E.g

```
$('body').on('click', function () { console.log('first') });
$('body').on('click', function () { console.log('second') });
```

Now,

The whenever the body is clicked the first piece of code/callback gets called.

Is there any way in which we can force to execute the latter attached event handler to get executed first?

Answer (score 1):

You can use setTimeout to force this behavior.

```
 document.body.addEventListener('click',function () {
    setTimeout(function(){console.log('first')},20)
 });
 document.body.addEventListener('click',function () {          
    setTimeout(function(){console.log('second')},10)
 });
```

or you could do something like this:

```
function callback1(){
  console.log("f1");
}

function callback2(){
  console.log("f2");
}

function orderCallbacks(){
  for(var i=0; i< arguments.length; i++){
    arguments[i]();
  }
}
document.body.addEventListener('click',function () {         
  orderCallbacks(callback2,callback1);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try it like this to delay the first event to execute:

```
$('body').on('click', function(){setTimeout(function () { console.log('first'); },10);});
$('body').on('click', function () { console.log('second') ;});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do would be to just reorder the `.on` calls, but I have the feeling you don't have the ability to edit the code that attaches those. If that is the case, there probably isn't a way of doing that.

Unless *all* of the handlers you want to precede were added via named functions that you have access to in your scope. In that case, you could just remove them with `.off` and then reattach them in the order you desire:

```
var one = function () {
    console.log('one');
  },
  two = function () {
    console.log('two');
  };

$('body').on('click', one);
$('body').on('click', two);

var zero = function () {
  console.log('zero');
};

$('body').off('click', one);
$('body').off('click', two);

$('body').on('click', zero);
$('body').on('click', one);
$('body').on('click', two);
```

Knowing the way most people write jQuery code that might not be the case since most people tend to use anonymous functions when attaching their events.

Beyond that, if you do have control of the source that adds the other handlers but for some reason can't reorder the event attachment, you could write some helper functions that add/remove handlers and manage all of the handlers in an array so you could dynamically remove/re-add them when you need to prepend the list.